# Inserting object in excel using Python

Tags: python, pywin32, openpyxl, win32com, xlwt

I want to insert a Image(object) in MS-Excel Report which i am generating using openpyxl utility. Is there a way to do it using some python utility?

Answer (score 3):

Openpyxl allows you to write images into your Excel files! Here it is in the [official documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/api/openpyxl.drawing.image.html).

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

picture = openpyxl.drawing.Image('/path/to/picture')
picture.anchor(ws.cell('cell to put the image'))
ws.add_image(picture)

wb.save('whatever you want to save the workbook as')
```

This code of course refers to creating a new workbook and adding the image into it. To add the image to your preexisting workbook you would obviously just load that workbook using [load_workbook](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook).

Comment: I am able to add the object using the code suggested by you. But i was looking for a code which can insert it as an attachment not as file as whole.

Comment: What do you mean by "attachment"? The OOXML specification expects all media files to be included in the package and this is what openpyxl does.

Comment: It's very clear : I want to insert an object and display it as an icon. I don't want to insert picture spanning several cells.